# Не могу записать данные в бд ОШИБКА SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key='7dbe9350af507557e399d349071f6c99' WHERE id='1'' at line 1' in X:\home\localhost\www\kbm\adm\functions.php:35
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 X:\home\localhost\www\kbm\adm\functions.php(35): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
>   #1 X:\home\localhost\www\kbm\adm\event-listener.php(13): add_key(Object(PDO), '1', '7dbe9350af50755...')
>   #2 {main} thrown in X:\home\localhost\www\kbm\adm\functions.php on line 35

```
function add_key($pdo,$id,$key) {
    $stmt = $pdo -> prepare('UPDATE users SET key=:key WHERE id=:id');
    $stmt->execute(array('key'=>$key,'id'=>$id)); //line 35
    $pdo = null;
}
```

Comment: `key` в обратные кавычки (`\`key\``) попробуйте завернуть

Comment: @teran сработало, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сработало когда завернул в обратные ковычки

```
 function add_key($pdo,$id,$key) {
    $stmt = $pdo -> prepare('UPDATE users SET `key`=:key WHERE id=:id');
    $stmt->execute(array('key'=>$key,'id'=>$id)); //line 35
    $pdo = null;
}
```

Comment: дабы понимать почему так - то `key` это ключевое слово SQL. лучше воздержитесь от использования ключевых слов для именования полей. дайте полю другое название, `akey`, `product_key`, `auth_key`, `secret_key` и так далее.

Comment: @teran спасибо, я и не знал. Тогда я дам полю название в честь вас - teran_key.